# SQL syntax issue with geometry

Tags: sql-server, geometry

I must be missing something pretty basic, but i have 2 tables.  Both are basic, just a primary key (as a uniqueidentifier) and a geometry column in each.  I'm trying to find if a point in one of the table exists in the polygon in the other table.

So this works without any problems (returns a row from PolygonTable):

```
DECLARE @g geometry;  
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (-117.6743333 33.8343333)', 0);  
select * from PolygonTable where Polygon.STIntersects(@g)= 1
```

and this works as well

```
declare @h geometry
select @h =  Point from PointTable where PointGUID=N'3B77C26E-ACAC-4328-ED94-08D5EDE20723'
SELECT @h.ToString();  // outputs POINT (-117.6743333 33.8343333) above
```

but for some reason, the following does NOT work

```
declare @h geometry
select @h =  Point from PointTable where PointGUID=N'3B77C26E-ACAC-4328-ED94-08D5EDE20723'
select * from PolygonTable where Polygon.STIntersects(@h)= 1
```

That query returns no rows at all.  it's the same thing at the top query basically, what am i missing?

here is a gist of the basic table settings:
https://gist.github.com/vishnu4/9bd70658b49c2cfa00ca81ff1d25bc84
you can use the queries i have above to test my results.

Comment: Discussion on this question has been **[moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80463/discussion-on-question-by-phil-sql-syntax-issue-with-geometry)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is because your GEOMETRY points are not in the same SPACE REFERECEN ID.  For the first case you are in SRID = 0, for the second case you are in SRID = 4326. This makes the Intersection returns an empty list.

Check this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stintersects-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Ok, sure.  this explains WHY it doesn't work, but i don't really know the best path forward from here to get my SQL statement #3 to work.  is there a way to update the data in the polygon table to have the same SRID value?  do i have to scrap that data entirely and build it in another fashion?

Comment: You could try to update the SRID in both tables to a unique one. But I don't know what the impact of this update will be on other tables or procedures you may have... Just to be sure, create 2 new tables from selecting both old tables and then update the new ones, for example 4326 for both and see what happens after that:   to update the SRID try this query.....  update TABLE set COLUMN.STSrid=4326;